# OLE DB Source not accepting variable as parameter

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, parameters, ssis, oledb

```
EXEC dbo.event @first_param = 'smth', @second_param = 'IS', @date_param = '2016-10-31 09:58:24.690', @databaseparam = 'dtp'
```

I have a variable **databaseval** with the scope of the whole package and Data Type = String and its value is **dtp**

However when map the variable to OLE DB Source editor I get 'Invalid object name .smth.mytable'. Does this mean that the dtp parameter is not passet or what?

This is not ok

```
EXEC dbo.event @first_param = 'smth', @second_param = 'IS', @date_param = '2016-10-31 09:58:24.690', @databaseparam = ?
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: How do you map your variable to OLE DB Source - a screenshot wшер mapping will be beneficial.

Comment: In the parameters I put  @databaseparam and in the variables User::databaseval

Comment: Is `mytable` the default value for `databaseval` variable?

Comment: No, it´s dtp so the query should be select * from dtp.smth.mytable . First part of the three part identifier i.e the database name

Comment: Please check definition of databaseval Variable **default value**; looks like its default value is an empty string. You get your error from DFT Source Validation step when your query is being executed against data source.

Comment: I have the variable window on the left side and dtp is a value given by me and no operations are made concerning databaseval

Comment: Please add the code of `dbo.event` to your question.   The actual problem could be there.

Answer (score 0):

> In the parameters I put @databaseparam and in the variables
>   User::databaseval

Don't use the parameter name in the parameter mapping.   Instead, use the index of its position in the query.

For example, if it's the only mapped parameter in the query, then use `0`.

Comment: EXEC dbo.tapaht /@/one_param = 'm300', /@/type_param = 'TS', /@/date_param = '2016-10-31 09:58:24.690', /@/db_param =?   and int the set query parameters: parameters=0 and variables =  User::databaseval

Comment: User::databaseval = mydb    still it seems to think that the variable databaseval is empty, since I get an error invalid object name .smth.table and it should be  mydb.smth.table

Comment: What have you done to confirm that the variable is not empty?   Maybe it is.

Comment: I'm showing the variable in msgbox before running the OLE db part and the value is given by user, before running the package, so it is "hard coded" to the variable. I can also see the value in varibles window.

Comment: The variable is string type. So it is possible that sql does not know it is varchar is possible, but it should be type casted in the stored procedure. To me it sounds like a type mismatch problem, but I don´t know how to check/fix it, since I get no errors related to that and none of the guides talk suggest typecasting the variable(visual studio) in SQL

Comment: Doesn't sound like a type casting problem to me.   It could help if you post some screenshots of the parts of the package involved in the behavior, and maybe we'll see something that you are missing.   You could also run profiler to see exactly what command the package is sending to your sql server.